# How to test if a button is displayed in vue

Tags: vue.js

I’m trying to test if my sign in will not work if no values are given for email and password. I thought of doing this by testing if the logout button is displayed after clicking on the sign in button.
This is what I have so far:

Login.vue

```
 <button id="signIn" v-on:click="signIn" >Sign in</button>
```

Main.vue

```
<button id="logout" v-on:click="logout">Logout</button>
```

login.spec.js

```
describe('Non existent user', () =>{
it('should not allow sign in', () =>{
    const wrapper = shallow(Login)
    const wrapper2 = shallow(Main)
    const signIn = wrapper.find('#signIn')
    signIn.trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper2.find('#logout').hasStyle('display', 'none')).toBe(true)
```

The test shows it to be false when it should be true since its not displayed and I don’t know how to test it differently.

Comment: Could you maybe prepare the example on codesandbox.io ? It has support for testing and npm packages anf stuff. I guess you use `vue-test-utils`. It's very hard to guess what's wrong with out more context about how `Login` and `Main` communicate.

Comment: It has too many modules for codesandbox.io, is their anything else I could provide to make things clearer? I know that clicking sign in without  fields filled will not sign as i've done that in chrome, I'd like to know how to write the unit test to show that though.

Comment: Are you using `v-if` or `v-show` to hide the logout button? Maybe you are looking for `expect(wrapper.contains('#logout')).toBe(false)`

Comment: The logout is on the Main.vue and that is loaded instead of Login.vue if sign is successful, is their a way to test if Main.vue has been loaded after sign in clicked?

Comment: How are you disabling/hiding the logout button? I don't see no `v-if` or `v-show`.

Comment: A different vue page is loaded, so if they logged out then login.vue would be shown

Comment: Show more code for that `Main.vue` template.

Answer (score 0):

Using async JS as we'll wait for the components to be re-rendered by Vue.

```
it('should not allow sign in', async () =>{
```

...

```
await wrapper2.vm.$nextTick()
expect(wrapper2.find('#logout').hasStyle('display', 'none')).toBe(true)
```

...

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/

**Edit**
.hasStyle has since been deprecated!

```
expect(wrapper.element.style.display).toBe('none');
```

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/330#issuecomment-356037493

Comment: `style does not exist on type Element`. This is with Vue3 at least.